# Chaining promises with Ember.RSVP.all and Ember.RSVP.Promise returning odd results

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, chaining, rsvp.js

When I do something like:

```
Ember.$.getJSON(url)
  .then(function(response){
    return Ember.RSVP.all(response.map(Ember.$.getJSON))
  })
  .then(function(response){
    // this is where the oddity begins
    console.log(response)
  })
```

in the `model` hook in my application router on my local environment (Ember 1.13.5), I get a weird response, in the second `then()`'s response, like:

```
Promise: {
  _id: 48
  _label: undefined
  _result: Array[1]
  _state: 1
  _subscribers: Array[0]
  __proto__: Promise
}
```

I can do a `response.then()` in the second `then` to get the response I'm looking for, but that is less than ideal since I would like to chain promises.

I tried to set up the same example on JSBin, using `Ember.run.later` to act as promises: [JSBin Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/difocibaqu/edit?html,js,console,output). The methodology seems to work fine here.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out `Ember.$.ajax()` and `Ember.$.getJSON()` are the culprits. They are causing the promise chain to fail. Upon replacing `getJSON` with:

```
new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  Ember.run.later(function(){
    console.log('resolving first fake promise');
    var response = [{id: 1, pool: 1, collection: 1}, {id: 2, pool: 2, collection: 1}];
    resolve(response)
  },1000)
})
```

It works. So I head on over to [ember-cli-ic-ajax](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-ic-ajax), and used that to handle the `getJSON` portion, and it works fine.

Cheers, jQuery. Cheers.